# What does resid >= 0x0100000 in AlertDialog source mean?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

AlertDialog source code has following method:

```
static int resolveDialogTheme(Context context, int resid) {
    if (resid == THEME_TRADITIONAL) {
        return com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_Dialog_Alert;
    } else if (resid == THEME_HOLO_DARK) {
        return com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_Alert;
    } else if (resid == THEME_HOLO_LIGHT) {
        return com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_Alert;
    } else if (resid == THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK) {
        return com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_Alert;
    } else if (resid == THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT) {
        return com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_Alert;
    } else if (resid >= 0x01000000) {   // start of real resource IDs.
        return resid;
    } else {
        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(com.android.internal.R.attr.alertDialogTheme,
                    outValue, true);
        return outValue.resourceId;
    }
}
```

What does 0x01000000 (I understand that it is 2^24) mean? And what expression resid >= 0x0100000 checks? Why resid should be greater than 0x01000000 to "start of real resource IDs"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bits 24-31 of an Android Resource ID is the Package ID.

Package IDs start at 1, 0 means this is not a base package.

So 0x01000000 is the "start of real resource IDs".

see the comments above "uint32_t id;" of "struct ResTable_package" in the [android frameworks source file](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/include/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h).

"struct ResTable_package" is defined as below.

```
/**
 * A collection of resource data types within a package.  Followed by
 * one or more ResTable_type and ResTable_typeSpec structures containing the
 * entry values for each resource type.
 */
struct ResTable_package
{
    struct ResChunk_header header;

    // If this is a base package, its ID.  Package IDs start
    // at 1 (corresponding to the value of the package bits in a
    // resource identifier).  0 means this is not a base package.
    uint32_t id;

    // Actual name of this package, \0-terminated.
    char16_t name[128];

    // Offset to a ResStringPool_header defining the resource
    // type symbol table.  If zero, this package is inheriting from
    // another base package (overriding specific values in it).
    uint32_t typeStrings;

    // Last index into typeStrings that is for public use by others.
    uint32_t lastPublicType;

    // Offset to a ResStringPool_header defining the resource
    // key symbol table.  If zero, this package is inheriting from
    // another base package (overriding specific values in it).
    uint32_t keyStrings;

    // Last index into keyStrings that is for public use by others.
    uint32_t lastPublicKey;
};
```